# How can I synchronize the "scrollLeft" property of 2 divs while scrolling horizontally within a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to "synchronize" the x-position of 2 "divs" within a react component. Eventually, I would like to have a table header that stays always visible and a table that can scroll vertically. The horizontal offset of that table header and that table are supposed to remain "in sync".

The "onScroll" event fires. However, changing the "state" of the property "offsetX" in my function `reactToScrolling` has no effect on my "divs" (as far as I can see). What can I do to make this work?

```
const { useState } = require('react');

const MainComponent = () => {
const [ offsetX, setOffsetX ] = useState(0);

  function reactToScrolling(e) {
    console.log(e.target.scrollLeft);
    setOffsetX(e.target.scrollLeft);
  }
  
  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ height:'200pt', width:'800pt', overflow:'scroll'}} onScroll={reactToScrolling}>
        <div style={{ height:'600pt', width:'1600pt', backgroundColor:'red' }} scrollLeft={offsetX}>
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style={{ height:'200pt', width:'800pt', overflow:'scroll'}} onScroll={reactToScrolling}>
        <div style={{ height:'600pt', width:'1600pt', backgroundColor:'blue' }} scrollLeft={offsetX}>
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
};

export default MainComponent;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eventually, I found the solution myself. It works perfectly if `useRef` is used instead of `useState`. When the scroll event fires, the `scrollLeft` property of `div1` is set to the value of the `scrollLeft` property of `div2` using the references created with `useRef`.

```
const { useRef } = require('react');

const MainComponent = () => {
  const div1 = useRef(null);
  const div2 = useRef(null);

  const onScroll = () => {
    div1.current.scrollLeft = div2.current.scrollLeft;
  }

  return (
    <>
    <div ref={div1} style={{ height:'200pt', width:'800pt', overflow:'scroll'}} onScroll={onScroll}>
      <div style={{ height:'600pt', width:'1600pt', backgroundColor:'lightgray' }}>
        ...
  </div>
    </div>
    <div ref={div2} style={{ height:'200pt', width:'800pt', overflow:'scroll'}} onScroll={onScroll}>
      <div style={{ height:'600pt', width:'1600pt', backgroundColor:'lightgray' }}>
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </>
  )
};

export default MainComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, this helped me a lot.

For a final touch, I just added another function for the top div so that it can handle the scrolling itself too.

```
const onScrollTop = () => {
div2.current.scrollLeft = div1.current.scrollLeft;
```

}